# How to use PayPal API to create checkout with items list and discoutn code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm using the Web Standards Payment and I think it is not secure because the user can edit it anytime and add a discount code.

I'm planning on switching to use PayPal's API but I have no idea how to use it.
Do you guys have any sample codes on how to use it with ASP.NET C# which can support multiple items and discount codes.

All I want to accomplish is a simple checkout and nothing fancy.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a secure SSL connection to prevent tampering. You should also be using PayPal's IPN to confirm that the amount sent to PayPal matches up with the original prices(s). You can use the freely available [IPN class](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/PPIPNDesc.aspx) from XDev Software to assist with this.

I put out a series of three articles on integrating PayPal with ASP.NET, feel free to use the code:

http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/paypal